# XML Code repeating outcomes, how to implement Distinct Values?

Tags: sql, xml, xquery, basex

trying to compare two columns by their price and publisher code. But Outcome is giving me double the amount of answers. Tried using distinct-values to not get repeated outcomes but keep getting syntax errors

I am using BASEx9.2 to run my XML file

```
<results>
  {
    for $e in doc("../henry/Book.xml")//Book,
        $p in doc("../henry/Book.xml")//Book
    where $e/PublisherCode = $p/PublisherCode and $e/Price = $p/Price
          and $e/Title != $p/Title
    return
        <Pair>"{ $e/Title }" - "{ $p/Title }"</Pair>
  }
</results>
```

my expected result is this:

```
<results>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Stranger</Title>" - "<Title>The Fall</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Edge</Title>" - "<Title>Slay Ride</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Beloved</Title>" - "<Title>Jazz</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Nine Stories</Title>" - "<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Nine Stories</Title>" - "<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>" - "<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>"</Pair>
</results>
```

my current outcome is this:

```
<results>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Stranger</Title>" - "<Title>The Fall</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Edge</Title>" - "<Title>Slay Ride</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Beloved</Title>" - "<Title>Jazz</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Nine Stories</Title>" - "<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Nine Stories</Title>" - "<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Jazz</Title>" - "<Title>Beloved</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>" - "<Title>Nine Stories</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>" - "<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Fall</Title>" - "<Title>The Stranger</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>Slay Ride</Title>" - "<Title>The Edge</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>" - "<Title>Nine Stories</Title>"</Pair>
  <Pair>"<Title>The Catcher in the Rye</Title>" - "<Title>Franny and Zooey</Title>"</Pair>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first want to group the books by the publisher code and the price with e.g.

```
<Results>{
for $book in doc("../henry/Book.xml")//Book
group by $pubCode := $book/PublisherCode, $price := $book/Price
return 
  <group pubCode="{$pubCode}" price="{$price}">{$book/title}</group>
}</Result>
```

Then you want to form your title pairs for each group, I think using a function for that help

```
declare function local:pair($seq) {
  (
      if (exists(tail($seq)))
      then
          (tail($seq)!<Pair>"{ head($seq) }" - "{ . }"</Pair>,
           local:pair(tail($seq))
          )
       else ()
  )
};
```

so with that you would use

```
declare function local:pair($seq) {
  (
      if (exists(tail($seq)))
      then
          (tail($seq)!<Pair>"{ head($seq) }" - "{ . }"</Pair>,
           local:pair(tail($seq))
          )
       else ()
  )
};
<Results>{
for $book in doc("../henry/Book.xml")//Book
group by $pubCode := $book/PublisherCode, $price := $book/Price
return 
  local:pair($book/Title)
}</Result>
```

Comment: It worked for me, I never thought to use a function like this, thank you

Comment: @M.Street, if your problem is solved consider accepting this answer as described in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.